# Variables set with PARENT_SCOPE are empty in the corresponding child scope. Why?

Tags: cmake, cmake-scopes

Consider the following minimal example:

```
.
├── bar
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

where `./CMakeLists.txt` is

```
project( foo )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

set( FOO "Exists in both, parent AND in child scope." )

add_subdirectory( bar )
message( STATUS "Variable BAR in ./     = ${BAR}" )
message( STATUS "Variable FOO in ./     = ${FOO}" )
```

and `./bar/CMakeLists.txt` is

```
set( BAR "Exists in parent scope only." PARENT_SCOPE )
message( STATUS "Variable BAR in ./bar/ = ${BAR}" )
```

The relevant part of the output of `cmake` is this:

```
...
-- Variable BAR in ./bar/ =
-- Variable FOO in ./bar/ = Exists in both, parent AND in child scope.
-- Variable BAR in ./     = Exists in parent scope only.
-- Variable FOO in ./     = Exists in both, parent AND in child scope.
...
```

Since the variable `BAR` is placed into the parent scope I would expect it to be available in the current child scope as well (and in those that follow) -- just like the variable `FOO`, which is defined the parent scope to begin with. But as can be seen in the above lines the 
variable `BAR` is empty in `./bar/CMakeLists.txt`, which lead me to
the following questions:

Why is the *modified* parent scope not immediately accessible in the child 
scope, `./bar/`? Can this be mitigated? If yes, how? And if no, what is a 
work-around? Or am I completely missing something obvious?

Context: my project consists of several executables and libraries. For a 
library, e.g. `bar`, I'd like to set a variable `bar_INCLUDE_DIR` which 
is added to the include paths of any depending executable, i.e. `target_include_directories( my_target PUBLIC bar_INCLUDE_DIR )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Context: my project consists of several executables and libraries. For a library, e.g. bar, I'd like to set a variable bar_INCLUDE_DIR which is added to the include paths of any depending executable.

There is a much better way to do this than to set variables in the parent scope. CMake allows a target to specify include directories, preprocessor symbols etc. that depending targets can use. In your case, you can use [target_include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).

For example:

```
target_include_directories(my_target PUBLIC my_inc_dir)
```

Comment: In fact, that's what I using. But since `my_target` is in a *sibling scope* relative to a required library `bar`, I use the detour via the parent scope to forward the location of the include directory.

Comment: You don't need variables to pass on that information. All you need to do is to apply `target_include_directories` on the library and all other target that use it will automagically get the relevant directories in their include path.

Comment: Aaah, now I understand what you mean. It's much better, indeed. Thanks for your persistence!

Comment: @nils The [updated documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_include_directories.html) says `Note that it is not advisable to populate the INSTALL_INTERFACE of the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of a target with paths for dependencies. That would hard-code into installed packages the include directory paths for dependencies as found on the machine the package was made on.` So, you should also definitely specify `BUILD_INTERFACE`

Comment: @nils If you manage to make it work for your sample project please post the code somewhere: I tried in a project I have and it wouldn't work, but it can definitely be because it is a complicated projected and there are several other things that my CMake files are doing.

Answer (score 20):

I do not see anything that is not consistent with the [SET command documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html)

> If PARENT_SCOPE is present, the variable will be set in the scope above the current scope. Each new directory or function creates a new scope. This command will set the value of a variable into the parent directory or calling function (whichever is applicable to the case at hand).

**./bar/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set( BAR "This is bar." PARENT_SCOPE ) #<-- Variable is set only in the PARENT scope
message( STATUS "Variable BAR in ./bar/ = ${BAR}" ) #<--- Still undefined/empty
```

You can always do:

```
set( BAR "This is bar." ) #<-- set in this scope
set( BAR ${BAR} PARENT_SCOPE ) #<-- set in the parent scope too
```

Grep for `PARENT_SCOPE` in the delivered modules in your installation, for example [FindGTK2](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGTK2.cmake)

```
if(GTK2_${_var}_FOUND)
   set(GTK2_LIBRARIES ${GTK2_LIBRARIES} ${GTK2_${_var}_LIBRARY})
   set(GTK2_LIBRARIES ${GTK2_LIBRARIES} PARENT_SCOPE)
endif()
```

Comment: Well, consider a variable `FOO` which is defined in the parent scope to begin with, then this variable is also available in the child scope (see the updated example). So why wouldn't `BAR` be available in the child scope if both live in the same (parent) scope? I would expect the documentation to mention such a behavior.

Comment: That could be possible seen as a [side-effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 14):

Peter explained well the reason for this behaviour.

A workaround I usually use in this case is to set a cached variable, which will be visible *everywhere*:

```
set(BAR "Visible everywhere"
        CACHE INTERNAL ""
)
```

`INTERNAL` is to make it not visible from cmake-gui. [`INTERNAL` implies `FORCE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html), making sure it gets updated if you change something for example in your folder structure. The empty string is a description string, that you might want to fill if you believe it's necessary.

**Note, though, that the correct approach is attaching properties to targets whenever possible, like using [`target_incude_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html), and propagate them to other targets by setting dependencies.**

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `CACHE` option. However, having understood what @Lindydancer meant, I tend to prefer that method.

Comment: This is definitely the wrong approach because it might affect every function and context in a random way. `CACHE` will clear the original value, `FORCE` will override the corresponding `-D` option. Instead of use the cache you have to consider to set a value in both contexts, in a parent and in a child instead of everythere. Otherwise do not use variables at all and use instead properties attached to a target or something else.

Comment: @andry The best approach is indeed to use as much as possible properties associated to a target, and propagate them all by specifying dependencies.
This answer address the need (if there exists one, I stated that it is indeed a workaround) to set a global variable visible everywhere, in sibling directories especially.

Comment: FORCE is redundant here, as INTERNAL implies FORCE. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to set a variable both in the local and parent scope, a [macro](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html) can help reduce duplication:

```
macro(set_local_and_parent NAME VALUE)
  set(${ARGV0} ${ARGV1})
  set(${ARGV0} ${ARGV1} PARENT_SCOPE)
endmacro()
```

Comment: What about `NAME` and `VALUE` args?

Answer (score 0):

Each variable in the cmake has it's own scope so it is dangerous use case where a variable automatically propagates in a child context, because it can interfere with it from a parent scope!

But you can set just another variable in a child scope to test it later instead of rereading a parent one:

`./bar/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set( BAR "Exists in parent scope only." PARENT_SCOPE )
set( _somerandomid_BAR "Exists in child scope only.")
message( STATUS "Variable BAR in ./bar/ = ${_somerandomid_BAR}" )
```

Now, if you have loops in your code, then you can test both variables:

```
foreach(...)
  ...
  # read a variable token name and token value, for example, from a configuration file
  set(my_var_name_token ...)
  set(my_var_value_token ...)
  ...
  # parse a variable name and value tokens into a real name and value
  set(my_var_name ...)
  set(my_var_value ...)
  ...
  if (DEFINED ${my_var_name})
    if (DEFINED local_${my_var_name})
      message("has been defined before and was resetted");
    else()
      message("has been defined before and was not resetted");
    endif()
  else()
    if (DEFINED local_${my_var_name})
      message("has not been defined before and was setted");
    else()
      message("has not been defined before and was not touched");
    endif()
  endif()
  ...
  # sets parsed name and value into cmake context
  set(${my_var_name} "..." PARENT_SCOPE)

  # Do save all values has been setting from this function to differently compare and 
  # validate them versus already existed before:
  # 1. If has been set before, then must be set to the same value, otherwise - error
  # 2. If has not been set before, then should set only once, otherwise - ignore new 
  # value (a constant variable behaviour)
  set(local_${my_var_name} "...")
  ...
endforeach()
```